# jQuery get method not working properly with two parameters passed to request

Tags: javascript, api, express

I am trying to send firstname and lastname to an api request using jQuery get method. It works fine with only one parameter ie with only first name but does when I add lastname to the request.
**It works fine if url ="http://localhost:5000/name?firstname="+h1;
but does not work if url = "http://localhost:5000/name?firstname="+h1+"&lastname="+h2; In later case, the desired output is displayed for a sec and then disappears and url changes to "http://localhost:5000/?", the function is called from "http://localhost:5000/"**
Here is my javascript code:

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $("#submitButton").click(function(e){
            var h1 = $("#handle1").val();
            var h2 = $("#handle2").val();
            var u = "http://localhost:5000/name?firstname="+h1+"&lastname="+h2;
            //works fine if u = var u = "http://localhost:5000/name?firstname="+h1; though lastname is displayed undefined in the output
            alert(u);
            $.get(u, function(data){
                $('.result').html(data);
            })
        });
    });
</script>
```

and here is my Express API code:

```
var express = require('express');
var app = express();
var path = require("path");
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 5000

app.listen(PORT, function(){
   console.log('server running on port ' + PORT);
})
app.get('/name', function(req, res){
    res.send("Full Name: "+ req.query.firstname + " " + req.query.lastname);
});
```

Comment: Note that *both* calls are wrong. The correct version would be: `var u = "http://localhost:5000/name?firstname=" + encodeURIComponent(h1) + "&lastname=" + encodeURIComponent(h2);` (or better yet, let jQuery handle it for you by passing an object with `firstname` and `lastname` properties into `$a.ajax` as `data`).

Comment: I suspect you've changed two things at once, and have incorrectly identified which change made the difference. `#submitButton` suggests this is being called in response to a `type="submit"` button being clicked. Since your code doesn't prevent the default action, the form that button is in will be submitted -- which would account for the page refresh you're seeing.

Comment: I used the preventDefault method and it worked, thanks for mentioning that.

Answer (score 1):

Your Ajax `$.get` request should look like the code snippet below. If the served **HTML** is also running via `http://localhost:5000/` then you can completely omit the relative URL.

```
$.get('name', {'firstname': h1, 'lastname': h2}).done(function(data) {
    $('.result').html(data);
});
```

The `name` in `$.get` corresponds to the route `/name`